# What is the state of visible fragment if we open a diloagfragment on it

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am in a situation where I have one activity and three fragments. At any given point of time one of those three fragments are visible. I have an option in drawer,which is attached to activity layout, from where I open a dialog fragment. So if I open a dialog fragment what should be the state of the fragment visible behind the dialog frament, like onPause(),onStop() etc? If I put a check like !isHidden() && !isDetached() && isResumed(),everything is returning true.

Answer (score 0):

`DialogFragment` lifecycle is tightly bound with container `Activity` lifecycle. If your `DialogFragment` is not fullscreen Activity and Fragment behind it should be in `onPause()` state.

Comment: So what should be the check in the background fragment, the onResume of that background visible fragment is still getting called,where I want to ensure some method doesn't get called if DialogFragment is visible . So what should be the check like isVisible() ???

Comment: `onResume` should be called for background fragment only when you dismiss dialog fragment.

Comment: If I go to background and come back the onResume() of background fragment is getting called as well,while the dialog fragment dialog box remains as it is.

Comment: that is expected because going to background will cause activity to pause and resume. in that case you should use `<your dialog fragment>.getDialog().isVisible()` in your fragment's `onResume()`